# Clickable TextView in Android\Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create clickable textviews in Android without success, in layout android I've the correct output but not linkable.

Here's what I have right now:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />  


        textTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(response.toString()));
        textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In

```
Log.i("myApp1", response.toString());
```

I've

```
<a href=http://...>MyLink</a>
```

Comment: What is the question? And what errors arise, if any?

Comment: I don't have error in layout android... I've the text Title not clickable...

Comment: @comex What do you want when it clicked? change in its style?

Comment: I need the value of `textTitle` clickable for redirect to link of my webpage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just should register a listener to this `TextView`

```
findViewbyId(R.id.textTitle).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onClick(View view){
        String link = (TextView)view.getText().toString();
        /* redirect to URL here for example: */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Or:

Add `android:autoLink="all"` property to your `TextView` and set its text a HTML `A` element. for example:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/mylink"
    android:autoLink="all"/>
```

And in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="mylink"><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML view is absolutely correct, make sure you have pragmatically handled the onClickListener properly.

Comment: In XML layout it is not possible to have in textView as html `<a href=http://lintomywebpage.com>MyLink</a>` ?

Comment: @comex Yes it is possible please my answer

Comment: @ABFORCE I replied you